# Logs creation in parallel test execution

Tags: selenium, testng

I am executing selenium test classes using testng and creating logs.
 In case of parallel execution of test classes using TestNG Factory, logs are getting mixed and bit confusing.
Is there any way we can create logs in parallel test execution in order of execution of test classes and one class logs separate from other.
 Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any logging framework for example: *log4j* and talking about separate that logs or talking about *TestNG* default logging? *TestNG*'s default logging **doesn't** supports it.

Comment: Right now, I am not using log4j instead using sysout for console logs. As a workaroung, I have added timestamp & testname with each sysout, so that they can be sorted for segregation at the end.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG has it's own custom logging framework similar. To control testNG logging you can add `"log4testng.properties"` to your classpath.

However as per [documentation](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/log4testng/Logger.html), there is **no way** to specify appenders or to control logging programmatically.

For logs which are not from TestNG you can use other logging framework than TestNG's default, like log4J. In that case refer similar question [using-different-log-files-for-every-thread-created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191401/using-different-log-files-for-every-thread-created)